# AFNetworking cancel successBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsoperation

I want to stop/cancel the operation in case of running the request again. Method `cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod` is working ok, but i have a problem when AFNetworking has already fetched the results and my successBlock is being fired - I want to stop it in the nearest future. But the problem is that operation.isCancelled is not cancelled.

The question is do i have to perform my 'very long successBlock' in `NSOperation` and cancel them too or is there any easier and faster method?

Code:

```
[[AFHTTPClient sharedInstance] cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"path"];
[[AFHTTPClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"path" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
        for (longLoop) {
            // do something long 
            if (self.isCancelled) return; // this won't fire no matter how often i run it
        }
    });

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // do something to fail
}];
```

Comment: Are you able to test `operation.isCancelled` in that loop.  You say "operation.isCancelled is not cancelled" but that doesn't mean anything.  The point is, is it *set*?

Comment: @trojanfoe Well, that's the matter and my question. I would expect it to be set, because i call `cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod` earlier (the code I've pasted is in a loop lets say), however if successBlock starts to run then even if i cancel it via `cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod` the flag won't change

Comment: So why the test of `self.isCancelled`?

Comment: @trojanfoe I wanted to underline, that this method isn't working. I'm asking what to do to know that successBlock should be stopped. Is there any faster method than inserting whole dispatch into NSOperation and cancelling it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended with doing `NSOperation` inside. Something like:

```
[[AFHTTPClient sharedInstance] cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod:@"GET" path:@"path"];
[operationQueue cancelAllOperations];

[[AFHTTPClient sharedInstance] getPath:@"path" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // add new operation
    MyOperation *successOperation = [[MyOperation alloc] init];
    [successOperation setResponseObject:responseObject];
    [operationQueue addOperation:successOperation];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // call delegate
    [self didFailFetchDataWithError:error];
}];
```